# How to Draw the Solution Curve in Julia with Arrow Correctly Using Plots?

Tags: julia

I am trying to plot the solution curve from this page:

[dynamicalsystem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyYqn.png)

But, I can't draw the arrow in the curve pointing to the origin, and the curve is not spiraling as well. Is something wrong with my code?

```
using MTH229, ForwardDiff, Plots, LaTeXStrings, SymPy
gr()

t = range(0, stop=21, length=10000)
x = @. exp(-2t)*cos(t)
y = @. exp(-2t)*sin(t)

plot(x, y, arrow = :closed, label=L"x(t)",
    xlims=(-0.1,1), ylims=(-0.1,0.21))
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not see a spiral, because the plot you have linked is not accurate (i.e. it has a wrong scale - most likely for didactic purposes). You can see that you have a spiral, by e.g. plotting the angle of the point `plot(t, angle.(x + im * y))`. The problem is that the plot absolute value of the points you plot gets very small very fast so these spirals are not visible.

Now the other issue is how to plot the arrow. The arrow in your case is just not visible because it is plotted at the end of your curve. I think (but maybe there are better ways to do it) that the simplest solution to pick a place to add it separately. For example after doing an initial plot add `plot!(x[240:241], y[240:241], arrow=:closed)` will add an extra arrow in the segment of your curve and the arrow will be visible (you just need to decide on the color of the arrow).